# How to correctly calculate time intervals between given sections of time?

Tags: python-3.x, refactoring, intervals, time-tracking

For a time tracking application, the day is split into five sections:

0:00 - 6:00, 6:00 - 14:00, 14:00 - 20:00, 20:00 - 23:00, 23:00 - (infinity)

These five "bins" need to be filled according to time spent in either of these.
For instance the interval in question starts at 5:00 and ends at 16:00, 
bin #1 contains 1 hour,
bin #2 contains 8 hours,
bin #3 contains 2 hours,
bin #4 contains 0 hours,
bin #5 contains 0 hours.
Any amount of time, beyond 23:00 goes into bin #5.

So far I came up with this:

```py
    sections = [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    for tframe in numericdata:
        if tframe[0] < 6.00: # starts before 6:00
            if tframe[1] >= 6.00: # ends after 6:00
                sections[0] += 6.00 - tframe[0]
            else: # ends before 6:00
                sections[0] += tframe[1] - tframe[0]
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 14.00: # ends after 14:00
                sections[1] += 14.00 - 6.00
            else: # ends between 6:00 and 14:00
                sections[1] += tframe[1] - 6.00
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 20.00: # ends after 20:00
                sections[2] += 20.00 - 14.00
            else: # ends between 14:00 and 20:00
                sections[2] += tframe[1] - 14.00
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 23.00: # ends after 23:00
                sections[3] += 23.00 - 20.00
                sections[4] += tframe[1] - 23.00
            else: # ends between 20:00 and 23:00
                sections[3] += tframe[1] - 20.00
                continue

        elif tframe[0] < 14.00: # starts between 6:00 and 14:00
            if tframe[1] >= 14.00: # ends after 14:00
                sections[1] += 14.00 - tframe[0]
            else: # ends before 14:00
                sections[1] += tframe[1] - tframe[0]
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 20.00: # ends after 20:00
                sections[2] += 20.00 - 14.00
            else: # ends between 14:00 and 20:00
                sections[2] += tframe[1] - 14.00
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 23.00: # ends after 23:00
                sections[3] += 23.00 - 20.00
                sections[4] += tframe[1] - 23.00
            else: # ends between 20:00 and 23:00
                sections[3] += tframe[1] - 20.00
                continue

        elif tframe[0] < 20.00: # starts between 14:00 and 20:00
            if tframe[1] >= 20.00: # ends after 20:00
                sections[2] += 20.00 - tframe[0]
            else: # ends before 20:00
                sections[2] += tframe[1] - tframe[0]
                continue

            if tframe[1] >= 23.00: # ends after 23:00
                sections[3] += 23.00 - 20.00
                sections[4] += tframe[1] - 23.00
            else: # ends between 20:00 and 23:00
                sections[3] += tframe[1] - 20.00
                continue

        elif tframe[0] < 23.00: # starts between 20:00 and 23:00
            if tframe[1] >= 23.00: # ends after 23:00
                sections[3] += 23.00 - tframe[0]
                sections[4] += tframe[1] - 23.00
            else: # ends before 23:00
                sections[3] += tframe[1] - tframe[0]
                continue

        else: # starts and ends some time after 23:00
            sections[4] += tframe[1] - tframe[0]
```

`numericdata` is an array containing intervals as tuples of start and end times. All time values have been converted to hours with fractions, so 13:15 is encoded as 13.25, etc.
As an example `numericdata` may contain `[ [ 6.75, 12.5 ], [ 13.5, 18.25 ] ]`, so two intervals, one from 6:45 to 12:30, and another one from 13:30 to 18:15. The resulting `sections` array would look like this: `[  0, 6.25, 4.25, 0, 0 ]`

I feel like there must be a better way to do this, than what I've come up with. It's entirely hardcoded, and I can't come up with constructing something, that reduces code duplication, and perhaps is a bit more flexible, such as defining the amount of bins, and their lengths rather than hardcoding them like that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly. The *split* hours are defined in list `splits`, so it's configurable:

```
data = [[ 6.75, 12.5 ], [ 13.5, 18.25 ]]
splits = [0, 6, 14, 20, 23, float('inf')]

def intersection(a, b, c, d):
    if a > d or b < c:
        return 0 # no intersection
    left, right = max(a, c), min(b, d)
    return right - left

out = [sum(v) for v in zip(*[[intersection(*i, *s) for s in zip(splits, splits[1::])] for i in data])]

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 6.25, 4.25, 0, 0]
```